# Can't declare an object in *ngFor iterator of Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I'm using the following code to iterate a bunch of custom controls. Since those need to know some stuff, like index and position in the structure, I'm passing in a config object to keep the junk together like this.

```
<div *ngFor="let thing of stuff; let first=first; let last=last; let index = index;">
  <app-thingy [data]="thing"
              [config]="{first:first,last:last,index:index}">
  </app-thingy>
</div>
```

I'd prefer to keep the code more compact and it seems like a very repetitive syntax with `let` this and `let` that. So I figured that I could create the object straight off in the iterative tag like this.

```
<div *ngFor="let thing of stuff; let config={first:first,last:last,index:index};">
  <app-thingy [data]="thing"
              [config]="config">
  </app-thingy>
</div>
```

However, Angular barks at this claiming that the curly bracket in the definition of `config` is an invalid syntax.

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
>   Parser Error: Unexpected token {, expected identifier, keyword, or string at column 45 in [let thing of stuff; let config={first:first,last:last,index:index};] in
>   ...
>   <div [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let thing of stuff; let config=

As far I can goolearch it, the syntax is wrong **but** I can't see why. Can someone, please, shed some light on **why** those two samples aren't equivalent?

I noticed that using `new MyType(...)` in the HTML markup isn't working neither but that's apparently by design. However, this is a anonymous object (type `any`) so I'm a bit puzzled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is wrong

```
<div *ngFor="let thing of stuff; let config={first:first,last:last,index:index};">
  <app-thingy [data]="thing"
              [config]="config">
  </app-thingy>
</div>
```

Because first:first,last:last,index:index referencing to loop condition, they are not handled as objects. You can understand it as  for loop in javascript like

```
for(let i=0; i<somelength ;i++){}
```

like `i=0` is equal to `first:first` and somelength equals `last:last` and `i as index:index`. They can't be passed like above.

Comment: So there's no way to obtain them into the `[config]` without all this `let`ing over and over again? It's quite verbose syntax, in my opinion.

Comment: BTW, I didn't downvote you and I didn't downvote @sajeetharan.

Comment: Yes, you can <app-thingy [data]="thing"
              [config]="{first:first,last:last,index:index}">
  </app-thingy>

Answer (score 0):

You cannot declare an object using let inside the component.html

**WRONG**

```
<div *ngFor="let thing of stuff; let config={first:first,last:last,index:index};">
```

Instead you can create the object in ts and pass it in the HTML

Comment: That calls for two follow-up questions. First being *how* - I can't access `first`, `last` nor `index` in the TS file, can I? I was under impression that those values were generated during the enumeration process, hence not being available in the component's logic. Second follow-up would be *why* - I'd like to know the rationale behind the design.